# Passing parameter to linux shell to clone from git repository

Tags: linux, git, parameters, sh, git-clone

I have a script.sh that performs the "clone" operation of a git repository. Currently, the script works correctly with the target branch written in hard on the corresponding line.

`/usr/bin/git clone https://my-url-repository  --branch master --single-branch`

If I replace "master" with "$1",

`/usr/bin/git clone https://my-url-repository  --branch $1 --single-branch`

it can't complete the operation because it doesn't correctly take the branch and throws a fatal error.

```
warning: Could not find remote branch e to clone.
fatal: Remote branch e not found in upstream origin
```

However, if I print on screen the parameter $1 or ${1}, the entered value is displayed correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    echo Building from branch "["$1"]"
else
    echo "Please, enter branch name"
    exit
fi
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you notice how you used `"$1"` in your test but `$1` in your git command?  Could that be it? ;)

Comment: How are you calling the script?

Comment: Don';t characterize what you're looking at, show it. c&p the command you issued and its output from your terminal buffers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I found another way to solve it. I will put it in the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

I could not specifically solve the problem, but I did find an equally valid alternative. Instead of waiting for the parameter in the script call, within the same script I request the entry of the branch name, and then the *clone* is done without problems.

The code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please, enter branch name"
read branchName
```

And then I use the variable like this:

```
/usr/bin/git clone https://my-url-repository  --branch $branchName --single-branch
```